# Which realised Managed Objects are turned to faults in Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I was reading through the documentations of `NSManagedObject`, looking at these two methods, I was wondering, which of the realized `MO's` turned to faults.

[image]

I assume it happen when *Did Receive Memory* warning is fired. 
Suppose a `NSFetchRequestController` is used to display rows on a `UITableView`, with batching. Which of the `MO's` will be faulted, the ones that are being used to displayed current visible rows on table, the realized `MOs` that are other than the ones that are being used to display the visible rows, or all `realized objects`?